# Conditional Max in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have to following query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, 
       TotalQuantity AS TotalQty, 
       TotalSales, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN MonthNumber = MAX(MonthNumber)
           THEN TotalSales END) as RecentMonthSale
FROM vwSales 
GROUP BY EmployeeID, TotalQuantity , TotalSales
```

Bu it gives me the error:

> ```
> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression
> containing an aggregate or a subquery.
> ```

Input View is as follows:

```
EmployeeID    TotaSales MonthNumber
  1             4000      1
  1             6000      2
  2             8500      1
  2             6081      2
```

Desired output:

```
EmployeeID    TotalSale     RecentMonthSale
  1            10000            6000
  2            14581            6081
  3            11458            1012
```

I want following column in my output `EmployeeID, TotalQuantity TotalSale RecentMonthSale` My View has the following column `EmployeeID TotalSale,TotalQuantity, MonthNumber`.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect the query to show?

Comment: That update hardly explains anything. give the exact definition of the table(s), the exact definition of the view, and what do you want the query to return (as in 'the total sales and the most recent sales for each employee).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query will show the output that you need, and will scan the table only one time.

```
select EmployeeID, sum(TotalSales), sum(case when MaxMonth = 1 then TotalSales else 0 end) RecentMonthSales
from 
(
    select *, rank() over(order by MonthNumber desc) MaxMonth
    from
    (
        select EmployeeID, MonthNumber, sum(TotalSales) TotalSales
        from vwSales
        group by EmployeeID, MonthNumber
    ) tt
) tt
group by EmployeeID
```

Comment: Just for curiosity. Will the view will be executed twice or once by SQL Server

Comment: @Tassadaque - twice. But with an index on `MonthNumber` this will not matter as it will likely be a very quick index seek.

Comment: @Tassadaque - made the version that would access table only once.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The usage of the over function really came in handy!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    vw.EmployeeID,
    SUM(vw.TotalSale) as Total,
    Recent.RecentMonthSale
FROM
    vwSales vw
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            _vw.EmployeeID,
            _vw.TotalSale as RecentMonthSale
        FROM
            vwSales _vw
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT EmployeeID, MAX(MonthNumber) as MaxMonth
            FROM vwSales
            GROUP BY EmployeeID
        ) _a
        on _vw.EmployeeID = _a.EmployeeID
        and _vw.MonthNumber = _a.MaxMonth
    ) Recent
    on Recent.EmployeeID = vw.EmployeeID
GROUP BY
    vw.EmployeeID,
    Recent.RecentMonthSale
```

If you just execute each of the subqueries and view their results you should get a good idea for how this works